# Why the mismatch between frontend and backend width?

Tags: microprocessor, core

Looking at Qualcomm's Krait core microarchitecture, I noticed there is a mismatch between the width of the frontend and the backend:

> 11 stage integer pipeline with **3-way decode** and **4-way out-of-order speculative issue superscalar execution**

Why is that and how does it affect the performance of the processor (for better or for worse)?

Source: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Krait_(CPU)

Comment: What do you mean by "frontend" and "backend" widths?

Comment: @Vasiliy I'm assuming that the decode is done in the frontend, and execution is done in the backend. I may be wrong, though.

Comment: Not all instructions take the same amount of time; just because there are more issue units than decode does not mean that issue units will be idle.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't familiar with this terminology regarding instruction decode and execution. However, I still don't see what exactly bothers you about this statement - could you please explain in a bit more details what is it that bothers you and why do you think it is non-trivial.

Comment: @pjc50 thanks! Makes sense, that's what I wanted to know. Make that an answer and I'll select it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I originally asked the question I was interested in learning how this mismatch could affect the performance, meaning: will the backend would be sitting idle waiting for decoded instructions? Of course not, but what was the explanation for that?

Apparently it doesn't happen because:

1. ARM instructions are very easy to decode (fixed-length) [1]
2. Decoded instructions take variable amount of time to execute in the backend, as pointed out by @pjc50.

[1] http://www.arm.com/products/processors/instruction-set-architectures/index.php?tab=A32+(ARM)